# Prevent Spring from Failing if One Bean Fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, undertow

We have an application that creates beans on startup using Spring's `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. What we're trying to do is not have Spring destroy all the beans created and thus cause the app fail on startup if creation of one of the beans fails. Is there any native Spring config or way to accomplish this?

I tried overriding the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` with my own Custom `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and catching exceptions within there. What was happening though is when an exception was thrown, all remaining beans were not created.

We're using Spring 4.3.0.

Comment: Why? When an exception occurs that basically means your application (configuration) is wrong, hence it cannot/will not start. So why do you need this, generally this happens when using the framework in weird/wrong ways.

Comment: Out app is an API with different endpoints, where each bean represents an endpoint to our API. If one bean, or endpoint fails, we still want the rest of the API to startup and have some active endpoints, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy way to deal with this is by [lazy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) initialization of bean using attribute `lazy-init="true"` in your bean declaration